# Assembly reference resolves to different path than what was specified

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

I'm trying to reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll in my c# project assembly. When running the project I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.50, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm really confused because when I right click references and add an assembly I navigate to a copy of the dll that I have in a folder contained within the project and add the reference. When I look at the properties of the reference, though, it shows a path of

> C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

and sure enough there is a dll in there by that name, but it's an old version. Why does this reference not point to the path that I specified when adding it, and how can I get it to use the dll at the location that I specified?

Comment: This sounds like a versioning issue with Oracle.DataAccess.dll also look at how this is being GAC or used .net 4.0 has it's own separate GAC vs .net 2.0 - 3.5 check this link out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284017/two-different-assembly-versions-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We take a couple of steps to resolve issues like this when we know that the specific version does not matter to the built application:

1) In the properties for the reference within the project, ensure the Specific Version property is set to False.

2) Save the project, the edit it in notepad or the text editor of your choice. Find the DLL reference and remove all version and key information and ensure the hint path points to your copy of the file. For example:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can be a bit flaky when it comes to references. Many times we have to just edit the project file directly. Setting the properties of the reference directly doesn't always stick. Right-click your project, select Edit Project File, and make the change there. It should stick.

Comment: I guess it's more than Visual Studio. How the references gets resolved is a process called as [Assembly Probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Agreed. However, what I said is still true. Sometimes the settings just don't stick, and altering the project file fixes the issue.